# iOS - Limit apps with push notifications priviledges to only be able to push essential notifications

Tags: iphone, notifications

Ive got push notifications enabled for certain apps on my iPhone running iOS16.

For some apps like Uber and Uber Eats you really need the push notifications to use the service, eg to know when your taxi / food has arrived.

The problem is some apps seem to take advantage of this and basically spam you with offers, updates and promotions, as notifications to your home screen which is really irritating. The Uber and Uber Eats apps seem really bad at this.

Is there any way I can limit these apps to only give me essential notifactions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot selectively disable notifications because iOS does not have information about what the notifications contain.

Apps can mark notifications Time Sensitive, and you can allow these to break through Do Not Disturb, but this doesn't really address your issue.

This means the issue is between you and Uber (for example). I believe that Uber does have a setting for promotional messages, if you can find it... Otherwise, you'll have to reach out to their customer support or find another app that respects your time.